# update_user_meta() misfires sometimes

Tags: plugins, user-meta

I'm trying to use `update_user_meta()` to create a trace of activity by placing calls in the code like:

```
update_user_meta(1, 'dbg'.time(), "R1:Setting href to: " . $href);
```

Then I  go into phpMyAdmin and look at the metadata for user `1` and see all the debug points that were posted:

[image]

This works pretty well. But I notice that if I place two trace calls in the code, one immediately after the other, like the two `update_user_meta` lines below, only the second one gets posted to the database:

```
$href = '?add-to-cart=' . $atts['id']; // e.g., ?add-to-cart=

update_user_meta( 1, 'dbg'.time() "R1:Settings href to: " . $href );
update_user_meta( 1, 'dbg'.time() "R1b:Settings href to: " . $href );
```

Why is this? It's annoying with this little trace system, but it seems like it could be a much bigger problem for WordPress. What if someone is actually writing two pieces of metadata to the wp_usermeta table, one immediately after the other. Will the first fail, with no warning? Does anyone understand what's going on here?

Comment: That's because they have the same unique ID and PHP runs in no time that `time()` is the same. Use `microtime(1)` instead? or `_1` `_2` ... ?

Comment: Yes!  You're right.  'dbg'.time() is the meta_key and because the second line is executed before time() has rolled over, both lines have the same meta_key.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Happy debugging :)

Comment: @Steve Posted your answer below, be sure to click the green checkmark to indicate that your question is resolved.